# Metro UI carousel not working

Tags: jquery, carousel, metro-ui-css

I have the following HTML code in an ASP.NET page. I have added the reference to the jquery script before the metro.js reference rightly, as metro.js uses jquery. I'm calling the carousal function from the $(document).ready() function, But still, my carousal is not working. What am I doing wrong ??

Edit : I am also getting a uncaught typeError: Undefined is not a function error in the console (chrome)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="Content/Metro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/metro.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        //$('.carousel').carousel();
        $('.carousel').carousel({

            auto: true,
            period: 3000,
            duration: 2000,
            markers: {
                type: "square"
            }

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="metro">
        <div class="carousel" data-role="carousel">
            <div class="slide">
                <p>slide 1</p>
            </div>

            <div class="slide">
                <h2>Slide 2</h2>
            </div>

            <a class="controls left"><i class="icon-arrow-left-3"></i></a>
            <a class="controls right"><i class="icon-arrow-right-3"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Yes @IrvinDominin ... I get a unacaught TypeError:Undefined is not a function error in the metro.min.js file

Comment: What is the the site that host the plugin css and js?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use

```
$('.carousel').carousel({})
```

and also use

```
data-role="carousel"
```

Choose one of them